# How to test in xUnit, UTC Date in millisecond for API method

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, autofixture

I am working on xUnit test for Web API project. One of the method takes UTC Date in millisecond, how can I test which confirms the input parameter to API method is valid millisecond. I have logic to convert millisecond to date

```
public static DateTimeOffset DateTimeCalculation(long milSec)
{
        DateTimeOffset epochTime = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
        return epochTime.AddMilliseconds(milSec);
}
```

test method

```
   [Fact]
    public async Task GetPersonMethod_MustTake_DateParameter_InMilliSecond()
    {
        //Arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        long startDateTimeUtc = 1626994800000;


        DateTimeOffset starTimeOffset = DateTimeCalculationHelper.DateTimeCalculation(startDateTimeUtc);

        //Act



        //Assert
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing unit tests, you should have a clear understanding about actual result and expected result.
Your test should look like below.

Alway's ask yourself, Given some input what's the expected output?

```
public void GetPersonMethod_MustTake_DateParameter_InMilliSecond()
    {
        //Arrange
        long startDateTimeUtc = 1626994800000;

        //Act
        DateTimeOffset starTimeOffset = DateTimeCalculationHelper.DateTimeCalculation(startDateTimeUtc);

        //Assert
        string actual = starTimeOffset.ToString();
        string expected = "22/07/2021 11:00:00 PM +00:00";
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
```